# Continuing to the next iteration in a For loop after an exception is found using Python

Tags: python, function, for-loop, continue, except

I have a For loop in a function that iterates through 3 different lists. An exception can occur at a certain point within the code hoever. What I want do is after that exception is reached. I want it to skip to the next iteration and go through the for loop again. The problem is when I catch the exception it ends the entire function and does not move to the next item in the lists. I am not sure what I am missing at this point. Please see the code below. thanks

```
def config_backup(host_device,password_list,site_slug):
    for h,p,s in zip(host_device,password_list,site_slug):
        try:
            host = h
            password = p
            slug = s
            # ssh into device (exception occurs here)
            # do other stuff
        except NetMikoTimeoutException:
           print("[%s] is not reachable from site: %s " % (host, slug))
        continue
```

Comment: Right now it doesn't do what you say it does (the for loop will continue if you catch that specific exception). Perhaps some of the code you have omitted is the problem?

Comment: Hello, the continue isn't needed at the end of the loop, as there isn't any code to skip. And are you catching the right exception?

Comment: Please construct a [MCVE] with code that we can actually run. There's too much distraction from the actual question here. On first glance, I don't see why catching the exception should end your function. But I can't tell you more without code that runs on its own and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Continue looping after exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306908/python-continue-looping-after-exception)

Comment: thank you all for the help. when i broke down the script into or more manageable view I was able to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll have to declare a variable whether an iteration should be skipped (if I understood what you want to do):

```
def config_backup(host_device, password_list, site_slug):
    skipnext = False
    for host, password, slug in zip(host_device, password_list, site_slug):
        if skipnext: 
             skipnext = False
             continue
        try:
            # ssh into device (exception occurs here)
            # do other stuff
        except NetMikoTimeoutException:
           print("[%s] is not reachable from site: %s " % (host, slug))
           skipnext = True
        #continue #continue at the end does nothing
```